# django virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a few questions regarding virtualenv in general.

I have found some documentation online about [virtualenv](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/), although I don't think my setup is installing something correctly.

Basically I am looking at seperating my applications into their own directories and I want to start upgrading django and certain other features for deployment to the servers.

So I have gone and installed virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
```

setup my new virtualenv

```
mkdir virt_env
vitualenv virt_env/virt1 --no-site-packages
```

according to this --no-site-packages your installation should only have the basics in it.

I have activated my virtualenv

```
source virt_env/virt1/bin/activate
```

and then ran `yolk -l` to see what packages are installed.
the result seems to be a lot more than just the basics as all my previous addons are still listed.

I have even tried to `deactivate`, change directory into the environment called `virt1`, reactive and then run `yolk -l` again.

Still it lists all my packages.

Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My guess that is has something to do with `yolk` rather than with `virtualenv`. If you just do `python` when the virtualenv is activated and then try to import a package which shouldn't be there you will see more likely what is wrong.

Comment: Correct, seems like it is an issue with yolk. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a yolk installed in your virtualenv or the global yolk installation?

```
flaper87@BigMac:/tmp$ virtualenv test3 --no-site-packages
New python executable in test3/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
flaper87@BigMac:/tmp$ source test3/bin/activate
(test3)flaper87@BigMac:/tmp$ pip install yolk
Downloading/unpacking yolk
  Downloading yolk-0.4.1.tar.gz (80Kb): 80Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package yolk
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./test3/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg (from yolk)
Installing collected packages: yolk
  Running setup.py install for yolk
    Installing yolk script to /private/tmp/test3/bin
Successfully installed yolk
Cleaning up...
(test3)flaper87@BigMac:/tmp$ yolk -l
Python          - 2.6.1        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload)
pip             - 1.0.1        - active 
setuptools      - 0.6c11       - active 
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6)
yolk            - 0.4.1        - active 
(test3)flaper87@BigMac:/tmp
```

I really suggest you to take a look at virtualenvwrapper[0] which is a set of extensions that help you on managing your virtualenvs.

Cheers!

[0] http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/